# VB.net Color one part of text -- Listbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, listbox, colors

In VB.net is there anyway to make a certain part of the string to have a different color to make it stand out?

This doesn't work but if I could something like this

```
string = ("How".ForeColor(red) & "are".FontColor(green))
```

Would it be possible to make anything similar to this in a ListBox?

If this is not possible is there a way to have it stand out more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to override the ListBox's `DrawItem` method.

Similiar to this: [Change the Color of Individual .Net ListBox items](http://www.thescarms.com/dotNet/customlistbox.aspx)

Comment: I have converted this to VB.net but I am stuck on how I change the color of a listbox item.